# SQL - How to filter by date then compare column values with matching IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

Given this date example:

| user_id | total | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19 | 2022-06-24 15:45:25 |
| 1 | 19 | 2022-05-23 12:48:34 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-03-23 09:23:55 |
| 2 | 199 | 2022-06-24 18:51:42 |
| 2 | 0 | 2022-04-17 13:32:32 |
| 2 | 199 | 2022-03-18 19:14:15 |
| 3 | 0 | 2022-06-24 14:26:45 |
| 3 | 19 | 2022-04-22 03:39:08 |
| 3 | 0 | 2022-01-05 05:55:12 |
| 4 | 0 | 2022-06-24 12:59:25 |
| 5 | 19 | 2022-06-24 22:21:36 |
| 5 | 0 | 2022-05-18 07:08:41 |
| 6 | 199 | 2022-06-24 03:15:25 |

I need to get a COUNT of user_id's
WHERE the for the most recent timestamp (for each user_id) the timestamp is "today" and the total in that row is > 0
AND for the 2nd most recent timestamp for that same user_id the total for that row is = 0.

Using the data above, the resulting COUNT is 2 (user_id 2 and 5 meet the criteria).  This is also assuming "today" is 2022-06-24.

I have tried this query (below), which works for all scenarios except when a user_id has three or more timestamps.  So in the example above, user_id 2 is not counted.

`

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.user_id)  
FROM table as table1, table as table2  
    WHERE table1.user_id IN (
        SELECT table1.user_id
        FROM table table1
        GROUP BY table1.user_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
     )
     AND date(table1.timestamp) = CURDATE()
     AND (table1.user_id = table2.user_id)
     AND date(table2.timestamp) < CURDATE()
     AND table2.total = 0
     AND table1.total > 0
```

`

Comment: What sql statement did you try?

Comment: What if there were two rows with the same timestamp, one zero the other non-zero?

Comment: @stu That cannot happen for the same user_id.  A user with two timestamps will always have different timestamps.

Comment: @AsadAwadia I have added one of my attempts above.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. I've used `CURDATE()` in my answer, assuming your DBMS supports this function, as you are using it in your own query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to number a user's last row #1 and their penultimate row #2. Then aggregate and use conditional aggregation (`CASE` expression in the aggregation function) to check the values. Then aggregate again to count the matches.

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select user_id
  from
  (
    select
      t.*,
      row_number() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as rn
    from mytable t
  ) numbered
  where rn <= 2
  group by user_id
  having max(timestamp) = curdate()
  and max(case when rn = 1 then total end) > 0
  and max(case when rn = 2 then total end) = 0
) matches;
```

For old MySQL versions replace

```
row_number() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as rn
```

by

```
(
  select count(*) 
  from same_or_newer
  where same_or_newer.user_id = t.user_id
  and same_or_newer.timestamp >= t.timestamp
) as rn
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am using mySQL 5.7.  So row_number() cannot be used. I have updated the tags.

Comment: Sorry about that. Why do you have to work with such an old version? There are some features that MySQL was quite late to finally adopt in version 8. Upgrade if you can. I've updated my answer with a solution for old MySQL versions.